# What's the best/KISS way to start an Xcode project linked to GitHub?

Tags: xcode, git, github

I want to use GitHub to make my repo, as it's easy to make the README, .gitignore, and LICENSE.

But I also want to use Xcode to make my repo, as it feels like Apple wants me to do that (default when starting a project is "create Git repository on Mac").

So now I have two repos with completely different files in them, and both have an initial commit. How do I gracefully resolve that? Or what's an alternative? I'm trying to Keep It Simple, Superhero while being robust / following best practice. (Yes, assume I'm a Git/GitHub newbie.)

Also, if using Xcode to make my repo: Should I worry about it making an initial commit before I can add a .gitignore? That seems like a code smell. (And I know you can ignore files in Xcode under Preferences -> Source Control -> Git, but the UI is terrible: one line at a time, and does it even support comments?)

Comment: To clarify, I am trying to avoid the command line. Just to keep it simple.

Comment: Create repo on GitHub. Clone to local. In Xcode create project and save into cloned folder.

Comment: Okay, that was sufficient. If you post an answer, I'll accept it. 

FYI, I used GitHub Desktop to clone to local. And after using Xcode to create the project, I have a folder structure like "MyGame/MyGame/…", which seems silly. But I used "git mv MyGame Xcode" via Terminal, so now it's "MyGame/Xcode/…"

Comment: I think people usually call it `src` (meaning "source files").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answer thanks to @matt.)

1. Create repo on GitHub.
2. Clone to local. (Can use GitHub Desktop to avoid command line.)
3. In Xcode, create project and save into cloned folder.

   - After using Xcode to create the project, the folder structure is like `MyGame/MyGame/…`, which seems silly. Can rename the subfolder via `git mv MyGame src` (e.g., command line/Terminal), so now it's `MyGame/src/…`